# How do you put headers and footers each of a html printerout

Tags: html, pdf, header, pdf-generation, footer

I am looking for an easy way to have headers and footers on html printouts, it can even be pdf print outs.

This is something that would be good to have when people are printing profiles on my platform, to be able to have a header that says, "John Doe" and a footer that says "page 1 of 2, Acme Inc, etc, etc".

Any elegant easy ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Internet Explorer or Mozilla Firefox browser then you can easily achieve this. Before printing you can go to File -> Page Setup. In Headers & Footers section you can set your customized text to be used as Header/Footer while printing.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use Media type print CSS. It has several features. http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets